# cross domain with ajax and .NET web app

Tags: .net, angularjs, iis

I am working with visual studio 2017 and I have two projects, frontend and backend. Backend is web API project and frontend use angular.js.

When I launch the applications to establish communication, both are launched in the same port, causing when I try to communicate by post from the frontend to the backend to consume API the web browser throw me a cross domain error.

How can I change the ports that is deploy the apps?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to set both projects to start, here's how assuming you haven't already done this.

1. Right click on your solution in the solution explorer
2. Go to Common Properties > Start Project
3. Set the solution to Multiple startup projects (choose whatever is appropriate to your needs)

Once you have multiple projects setup you can change the port (assuming you are using IIS express), here's how

1. Right click on your project in the solution explorer
2. Navigate to "Web" on the left hand tab list
3. Find the Project Url setting and adjust the host/port as necessary (see screen shot below)

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you Kane, but i cant find the "web tab" when i right click on my project, can you explain more this step? At the moment both applications starts in browser but in different ports

Comment: @FernandoTomeo, I have added a screen shot of what you should see, assuming you are using Visual Studio 2013/2015/2017

Comment: thanks kane, one more question, I should put the same port to my web application as the web api to consume their services and not have cross domain error?

for example:
at the moment I have
web app: http: // localhost: 62841
web api: http: // localhost: 62824 /

Should I set up a "Web" web app with port 62824?

sorry for the ignorance, I'm starting with this

Comment: cross domain won't apply as both requests as coming from the same host (`localhost` in your case). For developing using different ports is fine, however when you push you code live you'll probably want to use subdomains (e.g. https://api.yoursite.com and https://www.yoursite.com) or virtual directories. Using subdomains is far more common than virtual directories.

Comment: Thanks Kane and I'm sorry for my insistence, I'm getting this error "The response to the preflight request does not pass the access control verification: There is no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the requested resource. http: // localhost: 51435 ', therefore, access is not allowed, the response had the HTTP status code 404. "
I am building both projects on localhost but with different ports. I suppose this problem comes from there